# php array_merge not working for cookies id

Tags: php, cookies, shopping-cart, array-merge

i have a problem with php merge_array,  i am writing a cookie that gets element id from a button in an html form, then i make a cookie setcookie("info", $_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]+1, time()+3600).  I want to write an array that merges $array1 with ellement id from form and $array2 that gets the cookie elements. Problem when i click on the buy button on my page i always have 2 elements on the array, the new element and one from the cookies array.
Array ( [0] => [1] => Array ( [info] => 16 
 Am looking to get array $result with more than just 2 elements, so that i can use the id to get name, photo and other properties into the shooping cart

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
<?
$array1=array($_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]);

if(!isset($_COOKIE["info"])){
    setcookie("info", $_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]+1, time()+3600);
    $w = $_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]+1;
    print_r($_COOKIE);
}
echo"<br/>";
$array2=array($_COOKIE);
$result= array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Ok now that I better understand what you want to do here's what I suggest. Since you want to store historical data in the cookie and you want to maintain this in an array, you would store the data as a serialized array of ids in the cookie. What you do now is get the current ELEMENT_ID, add one to it, and store that value into the cookie which will overwrite what's there already. So I would replace all of your code with this:

```
<?php
    // do your checks
    if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true) die();

    // 1: if cookie exists, grab the data out of it
    $historical_element_ids = array(); // initialize the variable as an array
    if(isset($_COOKIE['info'])){
        // retrieve the previous element ids as an array
        $historical_element_ids = unserialize($_COOKIE['info']);
    }

    // 2: add the new id to the list of ids (only if the id doesn't already exist)
    // the cookie will remain unchanged if the item already exists in the array of ids
    if(!in_array($_REQUEST['ELEMENT_ID'], $historical_element_ids)){
        $historical_element_ids[] = $_REQUEST['ELEMENT_ID']; // adds this to the end of the array

        // 3: set the cookie with the new serialized array of ids
        setcookie("info", serialize($historical_element_ids), time()+3600);
    }

    // display the cookie (should see a serialized array of ids)
    print_r($_COOKIE);
    echo"<br/>";

    // accessing the cookie's values
    $result = unserialize($_COOKIE['info']);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply emmanuleG but i get same results, only 2 elements in $result array. I want it to give me $result array with more than just 2 elements as its doing now, whenever i click on the buy button to send an id into $_COOKIE it should keep adding to $result so that i have 1,2,3,4,5 and so on elements, which are ids.

Comment: Oh ok I believe I understand what you want to do but I need to clarify before I update my answer. You want to store the previous values of the ELEMENT_ID in your cookie so that when you merge you get a list of  all ELEMENT_IDs that have been submitted thus far. Is that right? So if someone submitted an item with id 3 and you have $_COOKIE = array('info'=>'1,5') you want $result = array(3,1,5); RIght?

Comment: @jobkwemoi Updated my answer based on what you want to do. The issue before was that you were overwriting the cookie's values each time so you would only ever have the current ELEMENT_ID and the last item you stored in the cookie. To fix this you would store the stuff in your cookie as a serialized array and update it by unserializing, adding the id, and re-serializing it to store into the cookie.

Comment: // adds this to the end of the array, when you say i should add this to the end of the array does it mean i should make an array at the end and add this as an element or just add it as line of code at the end?

Comment: @jobkwemoi Oh no that's not what I meant by that comment. When you do $array[] = 4; it adds the 4 to the end, or back, of the array. So if you have $array = array(1,2,3); and you do $array[] = 4; the array will be: array(1,2,3,4) because it added the value of 4 to end. So in your case you would have all of the ids in your cookie and you would do the  $historical_element_ids[] = $_REQUEST['ELEMENT_ID']; to add the new ELEMENT_ID from the request to the array.

Comment: Ok, i understand the point around adding the element at the end, thanks, but the code you wrote only outputs 1 element, when i click it replaces the element with the new one, so i should add some array to output all elements?

Comment: @jobkwemoi I am sorry about this but I left old code in the setcookie function before. Try the updated answer and you should see a list of all your ids in the $result array.

Comment: thanks a lot EmmanuelG, works like magic, now i can use the ids to get product name and foto to use in the shopping cart, thanks!!

Comment: EmmanuelG i have one problem, when i refresh cookie page it adds one more element, the element that was added last, i have tried working it out but dont seem to get through!